# How to truncated TextView without using Single line = true?

Tags: android

I have a `textView` where I am getting data from `JSON` and displaying. My problme is that I want to `store` all data into `database` but want to display few letters on TextView. I used

```
android:singleLine = "true"
```

Is there any way to show only few characters in textView but getting full data in background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:maxLength="10"` (for showing only 10 characters). Apart from `android:singleLine = "true"` if you want to show 3 dots at the end of the text then you can use `android:ellipsize="end"`

To store the full text data in database , store the json string which comes from server , however in the `textview` use `maxLength` property to restrict the number of characters. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi @Sash, I used both but it crossed ImageView and showing three ... on ImageVIew

Comment: What do you mean by "it crossed imageview"?. Please elaborate.

Comment: I have a textView adn at right hanmd there is a small dro down icon ImageVIew.. text touches that icon

Comment: set a right margin to your `textview`. Use  `android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"` and `android:layout_marginRight="5dp"` for your `textview`.

Comment: set `layout_marginRight="5dp"` under `TextView` properties in XML file.
It won't let your `TextView` "touch" your `ImageView`.

Comment: HI Sash, HOw can i set maxLenght==5000  through programatically in adnorid \

Comment: use `tv.setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5000) } ); ` , where `tv` is your `textview` Dont forget to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use in xml   android:maxLength="10"

Answer (score 0):

1. `android:maxLength="<Any character Length>"` (for showing only n
   characters).
2. `android:singleLine = "true"`
3. if you want to show 3 dots at the end of the text then you can use `android:ellipsize="end"`

> So storing the full text data in database , store the json string
>   which comes from server , however in the textview use maxLength
>   property to restrict the number of characters.

Hope this will help you !.

Answer (score 0):

`android:singleLine = "true"` doesn't have to do anything with the data in background. You will get your data in database as it is.

`singleLine` will only show the maximum data it can show in a single line on UI.

However, you can use `maxLength` to get exact maximum characters you want to show, `maxLines` to set maximum number of lines the `TextView` can be expanded to  and `ellipsize` to show that there are more words but it can not be fit in a single line.